# Robocopy behaviour (user profile folder)

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I'm copying with robocopy the folder `C:\users` to `D:\Backups` with the following command:

```
robocopy "C:\users" "D:\Backups" /e /b /copyall /MT:32 /r:0 /w:0
```

Instead of copying the folder content from `c:\users` into `D:\Backups` it creates a folder `users` and copies the content into this folder. Result: `D:\Backups\Users`

How can I avoid this behaviour and get the folders and the files directly into `D:\Backups`

Comment: robocopy is a DIRECTORY ORIENTED util. you give it the source dir & the target dir ... and it copies the 1st to the 2nd. if you want to copy ONLY the specific user dirs ... you will need to specify those as the source[s].

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm aware of that. Also I do not want to copy specific user dirs. The problem is that the command I wrote creates a subfolder. Instead of placing the content from `C:\Users` in `D:\Backups` it creates a subfolder `D:\Backups\Users`. I have worked a lot with robocopy and this behaviour is unique to the `userprofile`-Folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `/XF-Switch` and exclude `desktop.ini` then this will not happen.

`robocopy "C:\users" "D:\Backups" /e /b /copyall /MT:32 /r:0 /w:0 /XF desktop.ini`